# how to update a selected item in a dropdownlist asp.net c#

Tags: c#

Hi I have a dropdown list and I want to update one item when I selecting it in dropdown list,I wrote this code but it only update the first item:

```
        DBMethod db = new DBMethod();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string sqlcmd = "select * from dbo.Web_Personnel ";
        dt = db.ReturnTableWithData(sqlcmd);

        dt.Rows[0]["Job"] = txtjobE.Text;
        dt.Rows[0]["ChildNo"] = txtchildnoe.Text;
        dt.Rows[0]["Salary"] = txtsalary.Text;
        db.UpdateDatatable(dt, "dbo.Web_Personnel");
```

Comment: It is hard to see how selection of dropdown list changes anything in your code but this line (and next 2) `dt.Rows[0]["Job"] = txtjobE.Text;` is updating always first row selected from query.

Answer (score 1):

yes this code by default will only update the first item because you are hard coding value 0 in it

```
        dt.Rows[0]["Job"] = txtjobE.Text;
        dt.Rows[0]["ChildNo"] = txtchildnoe.Text;
        dt.Rows[0]["Salary"] = txtsalary.Text;
```

just declare a variable

```
    int i = 0;
    //change the value of I to desired value and less than dt.Rows.Count()
    dt.Rows[i]["Job"] = txtjobE.Text;
    dt.Rows[i]["ChildNo"] = txtchildnoe.Text;
    dt.Rows[i]["Salary"] = txtsalary.Text;
```

Answer (score -1):

Target a particular row using a variable *i*:

Identify the DB row to edit, eg:

```
int i = idOfUser // e.g. id = 3

    dt.Rows[i]["Job"] = txtjobE.Text;
    dt.Rows[i]["ChildNo"] = txtchildnoe.Text;
    dt.Rows[i]["Salary"] = txtsalary.Text;
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here?? this will update all the rows with the same value. txtjobE surely is a textbox

Comment: Fair point - I was under the impression @mahta wanted to update all items in the db based on the drop down.  On second thoughts, yes, this would be a pretty bizarre requirement.  I've edited, but now it's pretty much identical to your answer (sorry).

Comment: hi I changed my code to this but it dosent work yet
        int i = cmbp.SelectedIndex;
        if (dt.Rows.Count>0)
        {
           
            dt.Rows[i]["Job"] = txtjobE.Text;
            dt.Rows[i]["ChildNo"] = txtchildnoe.Text;
            dt.Rows[i]["Salary"] = txtsalary.Text;
            db.UpdateDatatable(dt, "dbo.Web_Personnel");
    
            
        }

Comment: int i = cmbp.SelectedIndex;
 if (dt.Rows.Count>0)
        {
           
            dt.Rows[i]["Job"] = txtjobE.Text;
            dt.Rows[i]["ChildNo"] = txtchildnoe.Text;
            dt.Rows[i]["Salary"] = txtsalary.Text;
            db.UpdateDatatable(dt, "dbo.Web_Personnel");
    
            
        }

Comment: Hi @mahta, what doesn't work - do you get an error message or are you getting unexpected results?  Are you able to update your question so I can read the code easier please? Thanks, Will